# Error when using tidytext to calculate word frequencies in R

Tags: r, string, text-mining, tidytext

I've been trying to calculate word frequencies with the tidytext package.

```
v <- "Everybody dance now! Give me the music Everybody dance now! Give me the music Everybody dance now! Everybody dance now! Yeah! Yeah! Yeah!"
v <- as.character(v)
v %>% count(words)
```

but I've been getting this error: Error in UseMethod("as.quoted") : 
  no applicable method for 'as.quoted' applied to an object of class "function"

please help! thanks!

Comment: I don't think there's a `count` method in tidytext by itself. tidytext can help you turn a document or string into a dataframe with words that you can count, tho. See answer below.

Answer (score 3):

`tidytext` is the package that lets you convert strings (in dataframes) into words and other things. You can convert your string to a dataframe and then use the `tidytext` method `unnest_tokens` to convert it into words, and then use `dplyr` to `group_by` the words and then `count` them:

```
tibble(v) %>% tidytext::unnest_tokens(word, v) %>% group_by(word) %>% count()
# A tibble: 8 x 2
# Groups:   word [8]
  word          n
  <chr>     <int>
1 dance         4
2 everybody     4
3 give          2
4 me            2
5 music         2
6 now           4
7 the           2
8 yeah          3
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a similar case and calling dplyr worked with the count() function:

```
tokens %>%
# call dplyr   
dplyr::count(word)
```